# Missing static resources from Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans

I have a Spring MVC 4.x application which has several static resources defined in the application context XML file as:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="classpath:/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="classpath:/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="classpath:/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="classpath:/static/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/static2/**" location="/static/" />
```

These files are stored in the "/webapp/static/" directory and in the "/resources/static/" directory (see mappings for `static2/` and `static/` respectively. There are some files in a "js" and "css" subdirectory which are accessible but the files I added recently are returning 404 errors when I try to access them via a local Tomcat server controlled via Netbeans.

I've tried many changes to my spring configuration and looked at the solutions in:

- [Spring MVC 3 Handling Static Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something)
- [Spring MVC Static Resource Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544854/spring-mvc-static-resource-mapping)
- [Spring 3 MVC Resources and tag `<mvc: resources />`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195213/spring-3-mvc-resources-and-tag-mvcresources/8195414#8195414)
- [Spring MVC not loading static resources from webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440502/spring-mvc-not-loading-static-resources-from-webapp)
- [How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)
- [Spring MVC Resource Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697878/spring-mvc-resource-mapping)

The farthest I've gotten is to be able to load an html file loaded in the root of the "resources/static/" directory, but am not able to get any files from "resources/static/vendor" to load in the web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem:

After nearly two days of searching and redeploying. I realized that the issue was not with my Spring MVC configuration. Rather, when I was deploying the application, Netbeans was not copying over all of the static resources.

Looking at the "target/" directory in my project folder I saw that only some of the resources had been moved. I suspect that these were ones that I had specifically edited within netbeans or that were in the project when I last did a clean build.

### Solution:

To fix this problem, I simply had to **build** the project over again before running it. This copied over all of the files in the "webapp/static" directory and in the "resources/static" directory.

Comment: had this same issue today in intelliJ, just had to force a rebuild a couple of times and it finally copied over